# How to merge a large number of excel files with the same structure into MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, excel, pandas

Excel file structure: a single excel file (.xlsx) contains 10,000 rows and 170-180 columns with 170 common columns.

Click [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Q4APLXktx_bVmuChfhsplAUyWR_TPnkE?usp=sharing) to download an example Excel file. However, I am facing some issues:

Due to disk space limitations,

I have tried to use Python to import the excel into MySQL to obtain an ibd file, but I encountered some problems:

1. Due to disk space constraints, I merged the excel files in batches and obtained 3 ibd files. Now I need to copy these ibd files to another computer, but I am not sure how to import the ibd files into MySQL on the new computer.
2. The ibd files generated by the Python code I used are about 5 times larger than the original excel files. I understand that this may be due to the different storage principles of file types. If possible, I would like to know some more efficient ways to import excel into MySQL.

Any guidance or links would be helpful, thank you for your help!

Here is the code I used to import excel into MySQL (using jupyter notebook):

```
header = "序号,标题,摘要…"
header_list = header.split(',')
header2 = "var001,var002,var003,var004,var005,var006,var007,var008,var009,var010,var011,var012,var013,var014,var015,var016,var017,var018,var019,var020,var021,var022,var023,var024,var025,var026,var027,var028,var029,var030,var031,var032,var033,var034,var035,var036,var037,var038,var039,var040,var041,var042,var043,var044,var045,var046,var047,var048,var049,var050,var051,var052,var053,var054,var055,var056,var057,var058,var059,var060,var061,var062,var063,var064,var065,var066,var067,var068,var069,var070,var071,var072,var073,var074,var075,var076,var077,var078,var079,var080,var081,var082,var083,var084,var085,var086,var087,var088,var089,var090,var091,var092,var093,var094,var095,var096,var097,var098,var099,var100,var101,var102,var103,var104,var105,var106,var107,var108,var109,var110,var111,var112,var113,var114,var115,var116,var117,var118,var119,var120,var121,var122,var123,var124,var125,var126,var127,var128,var129,var130,var131,var132,var133,var134,var135,var136,var137,var138,var139,var140,var141,var142,var143,var144,var145,var146,var147,var148,var149,var150,var151,var152,var153,var154,var155,var156,var157,var158,var159,var160,var161,var162,var163,var164,var165,var166,var167,var168,var169,var170,var171,var172,var173"
header2_list = header2.split(',')

import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:123456@localhost/ldz')

start = datetime.datetime.now()
print('本次运行开始时间：'+str(start))

# 连接MySQL数据库
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='123456', database='ldz')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# 文件夹路径
# folder_path = input('請輸入文件夾：')  # 目标目录
folder_path = r"E:\BaiduNetdiskDownload\浩大工程\ldz000"  # 目标目录

# 使用glob模块获取所有xlsx文件的路径
xlsx_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '**/*.xlsx'), recursive=True)

# 存储每个文件的路径和名称到一个列表中
file_paths = []
for file_path in xlsx_files:
    file_paths.append(file_path)

# print(file_paths)
print(str(len(file_paths))+"\n")

for item in file_paths:
    data = pd.read_excel(item)
    print(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + "  正在處理：" + str(item)+" 長度爲："+ str(len(data))+" 列數爲："+str(len(data.columns)))
    data = data.reindex(columns=header_list)
#     print("    chulihou" + str(item)+" changdu,"+ str(len(data))+" lieshu,"+str(len(data.columns)))
    data.columns = header2_list
    data.fillna('', inplace=True)

    # 将数据逐行存入数据库
    data.to_sql('ldz0', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

# 关闭数据库连接
print(str("  关闭数据库连接：" + str(datetime.datetime.now())) )
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Are all columns same in all excel files?

Comment: *I am not sure how to import the ibd files into MySQL on the new computer* Read about ``ALTER TABLE {DISCARD | IMPORT} TABLESPACE``. *Due to disk space limitations* This is not allowed for the database server. Expand the disk space.

Comment: Please allow me to explain it this way: excel1.xlsx contains columns A, B, and C. excel2.xlsx contains columns A, B, C, and D. All files have columns A, B, and C, and I want to import these columns into MySQL.

In fact, all my files are similar to excel1.xlsx and excel2.xlsx, each occupying about half of the total files. Therefore, if it is required to have identical columns, perhaps I can execute it in two parts.

Comment: Don't re-explain it in a comment - improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with the following steps.

First create the same table.

```
create schema ldz;
CREATE TABLE ldz.ldz174 LIKE ldz.demo;
```

Then run

```
ALTER TABLE ldz.ldz174 DISCARD TABLESPACE;
```

Copy your ibd file to the mysql data directory, then

```
ALTER TABLE ldz.ldz174 IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```